# Tensorflow Log Loss function ends up being a vector?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement multiclass log loss function in tensorflow. Here is what I came up with:

```
    #self.sampled_actions:     Tensor [batchsize, 2]   [[0,1], [1,0], .......] 
    #                          which is one hot encoded
    #self.probability:         Tensor [batchsize, 2]   [[.4,.6], [.3,.7], .....]
    #                          Represents probability of each class by neural net output
    #self.discounted_rewards   Tensor [batchsize, 1]   [0.4 0.5 0.5 -0.1, .....]
    #                          Differenc weights for different data points

    self.batch_loss = tf.log(tf.reduce_sum(self.sampled_actions * self.probability, axis=1))*self.discounted_rewards
    self.loss = -tf.reduce_sum(  self.batch_loss , axis=0)
```

However, my loss function ends up being a vector instead of a single value. Anywhere where I am going wrong?

Comment: Remove axis=0 so it returns a scalar.

Comment: @Patwie Doesn't axis=0 mean to reduce on the 0th axis, i.e. to sum all the elements up?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the axis=0.
Please see some examples of reduce_sum from the offical TensorFlow site:

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
tf.reduce_sum(x)  # 6
tf.reduce_sum(x, 0)  # [2, 2, 2]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1)  # [3, 3]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1, keepdims=True)  # [[3], [3]]
tf.reduce_sum(x, [0, 1])  # 6
```